# how to solve the problems when add this latest dependency "com.google.android.material:material"?

Tags: android, dependencies, material-design, floating-action-button, androidx

I am using this dependency in a project :

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
```

but now if I want to update it to the latest one the design is missed up , is there a way to handle this, should I change things in the layouts, styles or theme or something ?! the reason I want to update is to use ExtendedFloatingActionButton and I cant with the old dependency, so when I update it to this:

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10'
```

the whole design is becoming disaster, please help there must be a way to solve this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: *the whole design is becoming disaster* doesn't mean anything without details. First of all switch to a [Material Compoments Theme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#4-change-your-app-theme-to-inherit-from-a-material-components-theme)

Comment: I mean the colors of the floating action buttons changing its become black and menu items colors changed , and yes it is Material components theme

Comment: By default the fab uses the colorSecondary as backgroundTint

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti how I change the icon tint color?

Comment: colorOnSecondary

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti thanks that was helpful, can you also tell me how to change the menu item colors? I used a style and applied it in the navigationview like this :         `app:itemTextAppearance="@style/GillSansTextViewStyle"` inside it I change the textcolor and it was work before the update

Comment: Use app:itemShapeFillColor and app:itemTextColor

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti thank you very much, one more question please, also the textInputLayout changed the background to gray ? how to change it in one step or I have to change every textInputLauout background?

Comment: based on colorOnSurface

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Thanks a lot appreciate your help, you are awesome ;)